# How to use expectNew for constructor with generic parameter?

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I need to inject a mock object into a method where a new `MyClass` object is instantiated.

```
private MyClass<?> c;

public void myMethod(final String s) {

   c = new MyClass<>(s);

   c.callToMock();
}
```

And the class I'm mocking has a constructor with a generic parameter.

```
public class MyClass<T> {

   public MyClass(final T t) {
      // do whatever
   }
}
```

Now, in my test, I've created a mock for the class.
When `new` is called, it should inject that mock.

```
@RunWith (PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

   @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
   public void myMethodTest() throws Exception {

      MyClass<String> myMock = (MyClass<String>) EasyMock.createMock(MyClass.class);

      PowerMock.expectNew(MyClass.class, "my argument")
               .andReturn(myMock);
      myMock.callToMock();
      EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();

      EasyMock.replay(myMock);
      PowerMock.replayAll();

      ...

   }
```

When I run the test, it doesn't catch the `new` call and just instantiates an actual `MyClass` object.
I don't know if it's not able to match the constructor or what.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `@PrepareForTest(MyTestedClass.class)` on your test class to prepare the tested class to mock the `new`.

Here is a fully working test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyTestedClass.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void myMethodTest() throws Exception {

        MyClass<String> myMock = (MyClass<String>) EasyMock.createMock(MyClass.class);
        myMock.callToMock();

        PowerMock.expectNew(MyClass.class, "my argument")
                .andReturn(myMock);

        EasyMock.replay(myMock);
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        MyTestedClass tested = new MyTestedClass();
        tested.myMethod("my argument");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly right. I ended up figuring it out shortly after posting this haha. Of course it was the most simple solution